# How does Append (,) work?

Tags: j

**Append** `,` says:

> x,y appends items of y to items of x after:
>
> 1. Reshaping an atomic argument to the shape of the items of the other,
> 2. Bringing the arguments to a common rank (of at least 1) by repeatedly itemizing (,:) any of lower rank, and
> 3. Bringing them to a common shape by padding with fill elements in the manner described in Section II B.

What is meant by 1.? Doesn't step 2. and 3. do this? Could 1. be removed from the list and the result would still be the same (I assume it cannot but like to understand why)?

Comment: No. item 2 only changes the length of the shape vector, not its product (i.e. the total number of atoms doesn’t change). Item 3 does change the product of the shape vector, but only ever by adding fill elements (zeros, spaces, aces, blank symbols), never ‘content’ atoms. But item 1 adds ‘content’ atoms. That’s why 7 + 2 3 4 is 9 10 11 and not 7 7 7 (7 0 0 + 2 3 4). You need the first bullet or everything breaks. In general you’re going to have to work hard to reduce the DoJ to simpler rules than it’s already cast in. Ken a genius focused specifically on that kind of mathematical reductionism.

Comment: @DanBron 's comment is really the answer to the question. Both question and answer are clear and to the point and get at a central aspect of array operations in J.

Comment: Strangely enough I didn't understand Dan Bron's comment at all until it clicked and now I don't understand why I didn't understand ...

Comment: J is often like that, Micha :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Reshaping an atomic argument to the shape of the items of the other,

This step will repeat an argument, if it is atomic, which is different from "padding with fill elements" (of step 3.). Compare the scalar `5` with the list `1$5` (i.e. a list of one element):

```
NB. scalar 5, atomic case (step 1. applies), argument is repeated
   (i. 2 3), 5
0 1 2
3 4 5
5 5 5

NB. list 1$5, non-atomic case (step 2. and 3. apply), argument is padded
   (i. 2 3), 1$5
0 1 2
3 4 5
5 0 0
```